# WebStorm Terminal Color

Tags: webstorm

I'm getting this unbearable white background in my Idea terminal. (WebStorm)

Does anyone know how I can change this?

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Open File > Settings, and head to the Editor section > Colors & Fonts section.  There, you'll see the Console Colors option.

[image]

Here, you'll get an interactive edit screen to determine what you want those console colors to look like.  Click on the one that's most afflicted and edit its background color to match that of the console window.

Alternatively, if this is from a vanilla installation of your IDE, consider filing a bug against it.

Comment: Thanks, changing the console standard output for some odd reason changes the background in the terminal - I'll be filing an error report.

Comment: I didn't notice a change with these steps even after restarting the terminal. Suspected a deeper problem and I'm currently resetting my PC. Surely not every windows user has this problem with current webstorm.

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps, you've changed color scheme of cmd. Delete the entire HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console key from the registry, it sets your cmd settings to defaults and fixes this bug.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me as well, but the settings from WebStorm should overwrite the one set for cmd. I changed all background settings from WebStorm's console color settings and still I had to remove my custom cmd colors

Comment: For nice custom cmd I recommend you http://bliker.github.io/cmder/
and you don't need change default colors of standard cmd.

Comment: It did fix the problem for me (It's against the rules, but--THANKS!) but I've opened a ticket with JetBrains about this. I'd rather other users not have to deal with this. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18164

Comment: I have tried a lot of solution after setting up the console font color settings but your solution has worked like a charm

Answer (score 9):

Open Registry and navigate to

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console

and remove

> ScreenColors

key

This will reset color settings of your "cmd" window as well. However till JetBrains fixes this issue there is no other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in WebStorm 2023.2.1 by doing

Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > [The name of my Theme] > Apply > OK

Related issue:

https://github.com/Shubham076/Dark-Themes/issues/1