# Intellij Idea built in console color problem

Tags: intellij-idea, colors, console

I am using intellij idea's console but the background of the console is coming as selected all.[image: intellij console color]
I tried to unselect the selection by "esc" and tried to change color schema but could not find color option for highlight. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don`t think that you can change the color of highlighted text in Intellij. The color comes from the os. Does the behaviour still occur after a restart?

Comment: Yes, it still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have some custom colors set for screen text and background in Windows cmd console properties. See [IDEA-145236](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145236), [IDEA-124182](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-124182) and [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692165/webstorm-terminal-color/24783905#24783905).

The solution for now is to set cmd console colors back to defaults - by either  editing the registry key or by modifying default cmd console properties.

Comment: Thank you for the response, this is a conflict of Intellij idea then. If I do not want to change windows cmd colors, I have to use intellij as is. But thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this. The background was colored only when I wrote the "mvn clean install" codes. I solved it by changing the background here. Editor -> Color Schema -> Console Colors -> Terminal -> Command to run using IDE
[Intellij Idea Console Colors Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgknI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the ***Console Color*** settings in intellij and change the foreground color to any color you want which will be in contrast to Black (*I've used white here*).[image]